# Trigger an endless Thread Even when the Function Terminates

Tags: c#, multithreading

The question is that, what happens to a thread when the function has already been executed and the thread is started in that function. (please see an example below)

```
    public int Intialise ()
    {
        int i = startServer();
        Thread readall = new Thread(readAllMessage);
        if (i == 1)
            readall.Start();
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Error");
        return i;

    }
```

I want 'readall' to continue (forever or till the application is closed) even if the function is executed. Is it possible? Because for me the thread stops immediately even when the true condition is met. Please shed some light.

Comment: What does `readAllMessage` do?

Comment: What does `startServer` do?

Comment: Who calls `Initialise` and what does it do with the `int` ?

Comment: How does it matter that what all functions do, the only good question. 'readall' reads messages cyclically at 10HZ via CAN protocol. You did not answer the question and downvote it. This information is enough for answering. Please dont downvote when you did not even try to get it.

Comment: Could you show us a bit more code please

Comment: I can not, as its a company code. That's why I gave the skeleton of the function. How do I make possible for readall to run endlessly. The question is very straightforward.

Comment: while(true){} will loop forever

Comment: @HughJones . It will also keep on starting the thread. I just want this thread to continue.

Comment: If the thread is not started, it will never run. If that function executes and i is not 1. `readall` will not run (and be GC'd as it goes out of scope). If `readAllMessage` executes (when readall.Start() is called) it will only stop when it's code finishes executing. Based on what you've said the bug (and fix) will be in the body of readAllMessage which you haven't shown here

Comment: (I did not downvote) You're saying the thread stops immediately, but you're not showing us what it's doing. Hugh is right `while(true){}` will create an infinite loop which will run until the process is terminated; which may not be what you want. Look at foreground/background threads.

Comment: Put the while(true){} INSIDE your thread method

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample1creating

Comment: If I understand you guys correctly.                                                                 void readAllMessage()
        {
            while (1==1)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }

Comment: I dont know how to add a code in comment, sorry for above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is your code slightly modified to include the loop.

```
internal class Program
    {
        public static int Intialise()
        {
            int i = startServer();
            Thread readall = new Thread(readAllMessage);
            readall.IsBackground = true; // so that when the main thread finishes, the app closes
            if (i == 1)
                readall.Start();
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            return i;
        }

        public static void readAllMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("reading...");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        public static int startServer()
        {
            return 1;
        }


        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var i = Intialise();
            Console.WriteLine("Init finished, thread running");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

when you run it, it will print:

```
Init finished, thread running
reading...
reading...
reading...
```

and when you press enter (see `Console.ReadLine()`) it will stop running.
If you change the `IsBackground` to `TRUE` it would *not* exit the process.

Comment: Thanks, this is I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you ask

```
using System; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ForeverApp
{

    class SomeObj
    {
        public void ExecuteForever()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.Write(".");
            }
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeObj so = new SomeObj();

            Thread thrd = new Thread(so.ExecuteForever);

            thrd.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Exiting Main Function");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fair comment - I am guessing this will be helpful to the OP tho

Comment: Sorry, But the below answer was making more sense to me... thats why I could not accept your answer. Thanks for your answer too. Really appreciated.

Comment: No problem, hope we helped